# 410 Gone error if I insert "shell_exec" or "$_SERVER" inside an HTML input form

Tags: php, http, caching, http-status-code-410

I have this very simple web HTML form on my web hosting:

```
<form method='post' name='myForm' action='saveForm.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='text' name='title' value="" placeholder='title' size='50'>
<input type='file' name='newFile'>
<input type='submit' name='saveSubmit' value='Save'>
</form>
```

If I insert the string `shell_exec` or `$_SERVER` into the input text (with or without other text before or after), the `410 Gone` error occurs immediately after submitting the form.
It happens on my PC with a fiber cable connection and also on mobile with LTE 4G.

I have already checked that my php script on the server is not reached at all, because its very first lines output nothing:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
exit;
...
```

After it happens, all other requests to my site result in waiting a response for at least 3 minutes ending with the "connection time out" in the browser.

If I try on mobile with LTE, so with another internet connection, the site is correctly immediately displayed. Because of this I should exclude that the problem is web hosting related.

I already tried these without success:

- reboot pc
- change browser, also in privacy mode
- completely clear browser cache and all others data
- reboot modem
- wget from terminal -> same waiting time as in the browser

How can I figure out the cause/problem?

Ps. tell me if I posted my question on the wrong stackexchange site.

Thanks

Comment: Is this happening with requests from your machine only? Sounds rather like there is something running on the server side, that tries to filter possible “attacks”. Have you asked your server admin?

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I'll ask them as soon as I can. That happens also on mobile.

Comment: What did the server admin say? Does the input `--` trigger the same behaviour?

Comment: They said that maybe there is a security block of that content.